# How can I install the MercurialEclipse Plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm new to java and installing plugins.

I have found the [link to the plugin](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE#download) I'd like to install (it's called MercurialEclipse) but what a mess is that, it seems too complicated. I need simple guide. Could you please help?

Comment: In Eclipse: `Help->Install New Software->Add...` then find the plugin.

Comment: If MercurialEclipse is ad bad as egit I'd recommend learning the command line tools instead.

Comment: I understand but i need this plugin for my course (im still a student)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Installing a plugins on Eclipse it is easy as putting the plugin jar file into the dropins folder of your eclipse installation, but in your case to install the HG plugin you can use the update manager, put the update site : http://cbes.javaforge.com/update  into your eclipse update manager .

Go to : **Help ---> Install New Software ... ---> Add**
then you can add the update site in this way :

[image: Update]

After that you have added the update site you can install the plugin selecting it, and going ahead with the step-by-step installation wizard ...

Comment: For knowing how to use the plugin watch youtube link http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9OBg6Zv0Tns&feature=player_embedded#at=20

Comment: I think this is out of date. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31381555/trying-to-install-mercurialeclipse-but-only-get-offered-codebeamer instead.