# Trying to install MercurialEclipse, but only get offered CodeBeamer

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mercurial, eclipse-luna, mercurialeclipse

I tried to follow the instructions here:

[How can I install the MercurialEclipse Plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9640261/1593077)

But instead of being suggested the Mercurial plugin, I'm only offered something called 'CodeBeamer' in the avaialble software dialog. What gives?

(I'm using Eclipse Luna.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a few years back, Eclipse has a feature called *Eclipse Marketplace*, which means that you don't have to bother with update sites. I usually use this feature when downloading plugins.

Select *Help* -> *Eclipse Marketplace* in the menu, and search for *Mercurial*:

[image: Eclipse Marketplace]

Click the install button for *Mercurial Eclipse*, tick the checkbox, and click *Confirm*.

[image: MercurialEclipse]